# How to add more than 254 Controls in vb6?

Tags: vb6

I'm working with **VB6** and I have one form with multiple tab controls.

When I drag and drop any **control** in form it shows me this error:

[image]

Comment: How many do you have?

Comment: What ? I am Not understand your question

Comment: @Boann since the question title is *How to add more than 256 Controls in vb6?*, I guess 256.

Comment: VB6? You have my sympathies :(

Comment: @DominicKexel Uh thanks for making out that I'm stupid but I can see you just edited it.

Comment: Practical limit seems to be [254](http://i.imgur.com/hqCVRAg.png) controls. I imagine its a 1-byte counter, plus the Form itself takes up the first name slot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VB6 has a limited number of *named* controls per form. To add more controls, you can use a control array. That means, give some related controls the same name, then you can access them by name and index number. So instead of `OptionAlways`, `OptionMaybe`, and `OptionNever`, you could have `Option(0)`, `Option(1)`, and `Option(2)`.

Also, if your dialog is very complex and most of its features are rarely needed, consider moving some options to additional dialogs behind an `[Advanced...]` button.